# show that $f_n$ converges to $f \in L_1$ in the weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Problem: Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions in $L_1[0,1]$ such that there exists a positive $g \in L_1$ such that $\lambda(|f_n| > R) \leq \lambda (|g| > R)$ for all $R$ (where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure) and
$$\phi(h) = \lim_n \int f_n(t)h(t) \mathrm dt$$ exists for all bounded measurable functions.

Show that there exists an $f \in L_1$ such that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the weak topology.

Attempt: We know that $\lambda$ is a probability measure on $[0,1]$. The goal (I think) is to show that
$$\int f_n h \to \int f h$$
for some $f \in L_1$ and all $h \in L_\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I think there's a problem here, $f_{n}$ is a function in $L^{1}$ but you are asking a limit for the weak* topology of its dual.

Comment: I'm confused about your comment. Can you explain?

Comment: It looks like the convergence you want to show is in the weak topology, not weak* topology.

Comment: There is no weak* topology on $L^{1}$ in general since this space need not be  a dual space.

Comment: That was a mistake. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the title weak* should be changed to weak.

We have $\int |f_n|d\lambda=\int_0^{\infty} \lambda (|f_n| >t)dt \leq \int_0^{\infty} \lambda (|g| >t)dt=\int |g|d\lambda$ so $(f_n)$ is bounded in $L^{1}$.

Let $\mu (A) =\lim \int_A f_n d\lambda$. Then $\mu$ is real measure which is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$. Let $f$ be its Radon Nikodym derivative. Then $\int_A f_n \to \int_A f$ for all $A$. Can you now complete the proof using the fact that any $h \in L^{\infty}[0,1]$ is a limit of simple functions in $L^{\infty}[0,1]$ norm?

Comment: Thanks. this helped a lot. When I try to pass to the limit of simple functions using the density of simple functions in $L_\infty$, I get two limits on the LHS and I'm not sure if I can change the order. Any hints?

Comment: @player1235 Suppose $\|g-h\|_{\infty} <\epsilon$. Then $|\int f_n g-\int fg| \leq |\int f_n h-\int fh|+\epsilon \int |f_n| +\epsilon \int |f|$. Can you finish?

Comment: To prove the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$, how can you swap the order of the limit and the sum?

Comment: @player1235 See the corollary on p.159 of Linear Operators, Part I by Dunford and Schwartz.

Comment: Why is $ \lim \int_A f_n d\lambda$ well-defined for any measurable $A \subseteq [0,1]$?

Comment: I was able to prove the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$ using the dominated convergence theorem on the discrete measure $\sum_{n =1}^\infty \delta_n$.

Comment: The limit exists by hypothesis. Isn't $\chi_A$ a bounded measurable function? @player1235

Comment: Yes it is. Thanks for the help.